# Overflow: hidden; forces a left align of my div

Tags: css, alignment, overflow, hidden

When using this class chrome left aligns my div, when i inspect element and remove and add overflow hidden, it snaps back to the center.....  not sure what the problem is

```
.contentbody {
    width: 74%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Probably would be best if we could see the HTML markup and styles for the parent element

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and a jsfiddle or a lvie link.

Comment: Probably it creates a *block formatting context*. Now without any HTML code and CSS of neighbours and parents, go figure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.contentbody {
    width: 74%;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: auto; 
    border-radius: 40px; /* this property can now be used without prefix */
}
```